# Checkbox is taking value true for all fields

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

Here is my code

```
 <div class="label-container">
        <label><%= t('select_a_prerequisite') %><span class="necessary-field">*</span>:
          <b class="sel-list">
            <%= link_to_function t('all'), "$$('input.list-subject').each(function(checkbox) { checkbox.checked = true; });" %>,
            <%= link_to_function t('none'), "$$('input.list-subject').each(function(checkbox) { checkbox.checked = false; });" %>
          </b>
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="categories">
        <% @aau_subjects.each do |c| %>
          <div class="each_category">
            <%= check_box_tag "prerequisite[]",c.id, :class => "list-subject" %> <label><%= "#{c.aau_subject_name}  #{c.aau_subject_code} " %></label>
          </div>
        <% end %></div>
```

In this when i click on "all" , it should make true for all check box, but its not working and checkbox are displayed with default true. please suggest me where i am going wrong , or any other solution for on click true and false.

Answer (score 1):

First of all im not sure which rails version you are using but link_to_function is deprecated. see this http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/link_to_function

i would suggest to change this

```
<%= link_to_function t('all'), "$$('input.list-subject').each(function(checkbox) { checkbox.checked = true; });" %>,
```

to

```
<% link_to_function "All", "select_all_loans()" %>
```

and create a js file in assets. and add this. i hope this would help you

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   select_all_loans = function(){
      $("input:checkbox").prop('checked',true);
   }
});
```

or do this

```
 <% link_to_function "All", "$("input:checkbox").prop('checked',true);" %>
```

Comment: i have used rails 2.3.5

Comment: does my code works.? if are willing to use link_to_function. let me know i  will change the `$(".select-all-checkbox").click(function(){` to function and call this function from link_to_function tag

Comment: No that code didnt worked for me and yes please change

Comment: made some changes to my answer. can you try please

Comment: confirm me if you do this in browser console for this page `$("input:checkbox").prop('checked',true);` does it check all check boxes.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83739/discussion-between-sanju-b-myh-and-athar).